# How do I detect if a link in my iOS in-app browser will launch the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl, nsurlrequest, url-scheme

I'm building an iOS app that has an in-app web browser.

One feature that [Tweetbot](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/) includes is the ability to detect if a link will exit Tweetbot when opened. Here's a screenshot of what happens when you tap an App Store link:

[image]

How would I go about detecting if the application is about to close as the result of opening a link?

**Update:** I suppose this question isn't being clear enough: I'm aware of the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods, and that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]` bits.

What I'm trying to figure out isn't *how to open a URL* or *how to know if a  web view is opening a URL* - it's about **how do I evaluate a URL to determine if it will result in leaving the application without opening the URL first?**

Am I watching for `itms://` URLs? Is there a clean and simple way to know whether a given URL will exit the application for more than just `itms://` URLs?

Answer (score 1):

I can't know exactly what another app is doing but most likely they implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Check to see if the type is a `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` then inspect the `URL` of the `request`. If the URLs scheme is a custom scheme then another app is going to be launched.

Comment: That sounds completely reasonable - I'm also looking to see if there's a way to do this that *doesn't* involve using UIWebViewDelegate, but this could totally work. Thank you!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the delegate for the web view? It's there to do things like this.

Comment: See my update above - I get it that UIWebViewDelegate is where I would get the URL, but my question isn't about that - it's about how do I evaluate that URL and determine if it will cause the application to exit. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `scheme` of the URL. If it's an http or https URL then the web view would normally just load the new page. If it's file URL then the file may be opened. If it's a mailto URL then the Mail app may be opened. Just about any other scheme is probably for another app. You can use `UIApplication canOpenURL:` to see if the URL can be opened.

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to @rmaddy:**

In an UIWebView you're only solution of detecting and intercepting links are `webView:shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:navigaitonType`: and check if navigationType is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` just as @rmaddy said.

What you might think of and seek to find is this, but it doesn't intercept links in the UIWebView:
// In your code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

// In your App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    // Intercept links from openURL and links from other components like UITextView - present custom alert and on the alert delegate either cancel or redirect to the link
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the question to be more clear: I'm totally aware of how to open a URL, but my main question is more around *what does that intercept code look like*? Thanks!